# Composition of an injective and surjective linear transformation on finite dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $S : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^4$ and $ T : \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^3$ be two linear transformations such that $T\circ S$ is identity mapping on $\mathbb 
R^3.$ Now I have to say what kind of is mapping $S \circ T$ on $\mathbb R^4.$
There are 4 options :

1. It is the identity mappping
2. It is injective but not surjective.
3. It is surjective but not injective.
4. It is neither injective nor surjective.

What I see from here is that as $T\circ S$ is identity mapping, so $S$ is injective and $T$ is surjective. Now we know that a linear mapping on a finite dimensinal vector space is injective iff it is surjective. So from that  $S \circ T$ on $\mathbb R^4$ is clearly bijective as it is a composition of two bijective linear mapping. **So none of the options seem to be right, as it may not be the identity mapping.**

So am I wrong in some way ? If anyone could guide me that will be a huge help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 4 is the only correct one: As $T\circ S$ is surjective, so is $T$ (but not necessarily $S$ - in fact $S$ *cannot* be surjective by the dimensions involved). As $T\circ S$ is injective, so is $S$ (but not necessarily $T$ - in fact $T$ *cannot* be injective by the dimensions involved).
Now $S\circ T$ cannot be injective because the first map $T$ is not injective, and it cannot be surjective because the last map $S$ is not surjective.

This also follows by noting that the image of the surjective $T$ must be $\Bbb R^3$ and then the image of $\Bbb R^3$ unde r the injective $S$ must be 3-dimensional. So $S\circ T$ is certainly not surjective and - as it is a linear map from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself, where injective, surjective, bijective are equivalent - also not injective.

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful explanation. It's completely clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem "injective iff surjective" only applies if the domain and codomain coincide. It does not apply to your $T$ and $S$.

Comment: Ah ! I missed that. Thanks for the enlightenment.